# C# compass rotation script in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, euler-angles

I have a compass object which rotates and moves along with the camera. Thus the rotation and position of the compass object is adjusted along with the player-controlled camera. Now, having attached a needle to my compass - I would like to have the needle point north.

That is easily done but having the needle point to a northern object. But the needle now doesn't follow the plate (compass object) it is placed on. I would thus like the needle to point accordingly. In other word, rotate singly along the y-axis.

I don't need code - I just need a broad idea of how to do that.
I would really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out :D
It was much easier than expected... Here is the code if anyone should ever need it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Compass : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Update () 
    {
         transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 360-transform.root.rotation.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mind sharing your hierarchy for this solution (e.g. camera -> compass -> needle)?  Is your compass game object pointing north and the needle just following?  I am trying to implement your solution with my code but can't figure out the setup you used.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to project the vector pointing from compass location to target onto the plane where the needle should lay on. [Vector.ProjectOnPlane](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html) might be helpful.
Something like this should work (not yet tested):

```
Vector3 dir = compassPos - targetPos;
Vector3 needleDir = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(dir, compassNormal);
```